# How to show $\mathbb{A}_k^2 - \{ (x,y) \}$ is not an affine scheme

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I am reading Ravi Vakil's notes and on page 137 (June 11, 2013 ver.) he explains why 
$U = \mathbb{A}_k^2 - \{ (x,y) \}$ is not an affine scheme in the following way (Please note I am paraphrasing it here):
Suppose $(U, O_{\mathbb{A}^2}|_U)$ is an affine scheme, then 
we have $ (U, O_{\mathbb{A}^2}|_U) = (Spec $A$, O_{Spec A})$.
By considering the global sections we have
$$
A = \Gamma(U, O_{\mathbb{A}^2}|_U) \equiv k[x,y].
$$
So if $U$ is affine, then $U \cong \mathbb{A}^2$.

The prime ideal $(x,y)$ of $A$ should cut out a point in Spec $A$ 
by taking the generic point of V((x,y)). However, on $U$, $V(x) \cap V(y) = \emptyset.$
Contradiction.

I don't quite understand the last part of the argument here. Do we know that the
closed subset $V(x)$ on $U$ correspond to $V(x)$ on $\mathbb{A}^2$? I would appreciate if someone could explain me in more detail how we obtain the conclusion at the end. Thanks!

Please note the following was my original question posted:
Let $\mathbb{A}_k^2$ be the affine scheme Spec $k [x,y]$, where $k$ is a field. 
Could someone please explain me how to show $\mathbb{A}_k^2 - \{  (x,y) \}$ is not an affine scheme?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Coordinate ring of affine variety](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/654029/115654) (although this question is phrased in scheme language, the proof is the same)

Comment: I see. Let me change the question in this case... Thanks!

Comment: @zcn I also have a question to your answer to the link you have given me (I can't put it on there because I don't have enough poitns..). Why is it that you only have to consider the inclusion $i$? I guess is it obvious that any other possible map will not work? Thanks!

Comment: Well, it is a matter of fact that the inclusion induces an isomorphism of coordinate rings. So if both the domain and the codomain were affine then it would have to be an isomorphism, but it isn't even bijective on points.

Comment: @user181350: (Just to repeat what Zhen Lin said) The point is that if $U$ were affine, then the inclusion would necessarily induce an isomorphism, which it does not. It's not necessary to consider other possible maps

Comment: @zcn So for affine schemes, two affine schemes are isomorphic if and only it induces an isomorphism between the global sections? (Would this be the correct way to turn the result stated in the link to scheme language?) Thanks!

Comment: @user181350: Yes, this is part of the statement that $\text{Spec}$ is an anti-equivalence from rings to affine schemes, with inverse given by the global section functor

Comment: @zcn I see. Thank you! Could you possibly tell me what anti-equivalence is?

Comment: @user181350: An equivalence that reverses arrows, i.e. an equivalence with the opposite category

Answer (score 1):

Here is a more detailed explanation whose actual content amounts to just what Vakil says. Suppose that $X = \mathbb{A}^2 \setminus \{0\}$ were affine. Then by what you said about its coordinate ring implies we have an isomorphism $X \overset{\phi}{\to} \mathbb{A}^2$. This induces an isomorphism $\phi^{\#} : \mathcal{O}_X(X) \to k[x, y]$ of coordinate rings. But we know by the earlier computation of the coordinate ring of $X$ that $\mathcal{O}_X(X) \cong k[x', y']$ via some other isomorphism $f$. This means $g := \phi^{\#} \circ f^{-1}$ is an isomorphism $k[x', y'] \to k[x, y]$ (writing $f$ in this way is unusual, and we usually just make this identification implicitly). As this is an isomorphism, the prime ideal $(x', y')$ must map to some prime ideal $\mathfrak{p} \subset k[x, y]$. But we understand the isomorphism $f$ very well, having constructed it by patching functions on open sets of $X$ together. In particular, we know that $V(f^{-1}(x', y')) = V(f^{-1}(x'))\cap V(f^{-1}(y'))$ is empty. But by the correspondence between maps of rings and maps of affine schemes, we get that this (empty) set must be in bijection with $V(\mathfrak{p}) \subset \mathbb{A}^2$. But this latter set cannot be empty, and so we've reached a contradiction.